# Does previewing/publishing an application created using App Maker need GCP account as well?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-maker, google-workspace

I am very new to GCP and G-Suite. I wanted to understand one basic thing:
If I create an application (to be used within a domain) using App Maker, do I also need access to GCP?

I have done lots of googling [https://support.google.com/a/answer/9142070?hl=en] but couldn't find answer to this.While watching to one video on AppMaker I realised that- I can create application which could interact with G-Suite apps but we **can not** preview/publish this application without having account/access to GCP as "previewing" an app actually deploys the app on App Engine which is part of GCP. Also "publish" would definitely be doing the same.

Can any one help me in understanding this? I want to start my page development in App Maker and want to spend money on GCP later, this is doable only when preview is not dependent on GCP?

Any quick reference would be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: AppMaker is dependant on GCP products (Google Cloud SQL), hence you need access to GCP. In fact, you should be redirected to page to accept the terms and conditions of using GCP products if you try to preview an app of appmaker without having used any GCP product before.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Morfinismo, two quick question - (1) Where does app maker use Cloud SQL? (2) when we do either preview or publish, app maker application will be deployed on App Engine [part of GCP] by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Maker is dependant on GCP products: Google Cloud SQL and Google App Engine; Although, the latter one is not being charged. This information is located in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql).

> App Maker apps usually store data in Cloud SQL, a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) service that delivers fully managed SQL databases in the cloud.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing detailed info Morfinismo

Comment: Hi @morfinismo could you please help me with your views on my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57087994/which-tool-to-pick-from-google-cloud-platform-stack-for-creating-a-pipeline